# How do I set up a redirect in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, redirect, vuejs2

I've used `Django` a lot and haven't wondered how redirection works in it, like `https://app.com/login?next=https://app.com/questions`. I was sure that the browser was doing a redirect, how silly. As I understand it now, Django is doing the redirect.

But now I am facing a redirect problem in `Vue`. I have a link like `https://app.com/login?next=https://app.com/api/oauth/?key=xyz`. This part of `key=xyz` changes.

I expect that, just like in `Django`, I will be taken to `https://app.com/api/oauth/?key=xyz` after logging in. But in `Vue`, it redirects me to the home page `https://app.com/home/`.

**Questions**:

1. How do I set up a redirect in `Vue`?
2. Perhaps I am approaching the solution incorrectly. What to read to understand how `Vue` redirection works?

**Disclaimer**:
I don’t know `Vue`. The `Vue` application was not written by me, I do not know for what reason the redirection occurs to the home page.

**Native problem**:
I have two services Z and X, using the oauth2 authorization scheme. The Z service is used as the main one (it also acts as an authorization provider, like google in many social networks). When I try to log in to service X, service X requests data from service Z, since I am not authorized in service Z, it directs me to the login page for service Z. The link in the browser looks like `https://app.com/login?next=https://app.com/api/oauth/?key=xyz`, but after logging into service Z. I am redirected to the home page of service Z.

**Add code**:

*/login/index.vue*

```
submitHandler: waitFor('login', async function () {
      try {
        await this.$auth.login({
          data: {
            username: this.login,
            password: this.password,
          },
        })
        this.$router.replace({
          path: '/overview',
        })
      } catch (err) {
        //  some code
      }
    })
```

`submitHandler` is for login form

*/overview/index.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>Overview</div>
</template>
<script>
import {DASHBOARD} from '@/components/routesConstants'

export default {
  fetch({redirect, }) {
    return redirect({name: DASHBOARD})
  },
}
</script>
```

**Url example**: https://Z.app.net/login?next=/api/o/authorize/?client_id=xxx&nonce=bee&redirect_uri=http://X.app.net/oauth/providers/appZ/callback&response_type=code&scope=read&state=123

Comment: Django/Python runs server side. Vue (normally) runs as JS in the browser so instead of a "redirect" you would normally tell tell the browser to call an API rather than redirect (or more accurately navigate somewhere).  Can you provide more details/code of the "native problem" ie how you are calling this auth flow in the vue app? I don't think a "redirect" will help on first glance

Comment: @Matt How to capture or get parameters for a redirect?

Comment: found this.$route.query